# Does AES-GCM in .net core web api relies on machine key?

Tags: encryption, .net-core-3.1, aes-gcm

I have developed .net core 3.1 web api for encrypting and decrypting(using AesGCM technique),I want to host this application on 2 servers(has IIS) and there is load balancer infront of them.

So my question is does AesGCM algorithm relays on machine key? because i don't want to get into the situation that one machine encrypt and other machine won't be able to decrypt.

In the current implementation i tried adding machine key element in the web.config but there is no effect of it.

My other question is AesGCM is the best technique to go for encryption/decryption in .net core 3.1? need your suggestion?